# Storing a result in a memory address stored in a register LC3

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm a complete beginner to assembly and the LC3, but I am trying to create a program that will put values (1-15) into an array-like structure from x4000 to x4015. I'm having trouble with storing a of a register into the memory address that is contained in a register. Here is what I have, but I don't expect that really any of it is working properly, with the main problem being the STI:

```
.ORIG x3000
LEA R1, start
AND R0, R0, #0
AND R2, R2, #0
ADD R4 R2, #-15
ADD R3, R2, R4
BRz #5
STI R3, R1
ADD R0, R0, #1
ADD R1, R1, #1
ADD R2, R2, #1
BRnzp #-8
TRAP x27

start .fill x4000
.END
```

The code listed does not compile with the error "Line 8: Expected label or 9 bit signed PC offset, but found 'R1' instead" (Line 8 is STI R3, R1). Without placing R1 there I am not sure how I can use my address, though.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: STI (store indirect) uses one register as a pointer, the other as the data to be stored.  It's exactly the instruction you want.  Double-check the manual for it to make sure of syntax and which register is used as the store address and which as the store data.  What happens when you run this code?  Do you get an error message?  Does the data in memory not match what you expect?  This isn't a [mcve] if you don't include the wrong results.

Comment: The code listed does not compile with the error "Line 8: Expected label or 9 bit signed PC offset, but found 'R1' instead" (Line 8 is STI R3, R1). Without placing R1 there I am not sure how I can use my address, though. My apologies for not posting a minimal reproducible example, I will make sure to read this and keep it in mind as I post in the future!

Comment: You can and should [edit[ this question to fix it, like basically add that last comment as a new paragraph.

Comment: Ope, just did it! :)

Comment: Oh, oops, STI is Store *memory*-indirect, using a value loaded from memory as an address.  Use STR for register-indirect.  Read a manual, e.g. https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cse240-Fall05/handouts/Ch05.pdf has an ISA reference.  e.g. a google search for `lc3 sti example` answered this question in about a minute.

Comment: duplicate of [LC-3 STR with R1 as offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44056290) but I already used my close vote on lacking a MCVE before that was fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Peter! That link you sent was a great help :D I had the ordering wrong of my STR.